# Jquery Submitting Form without Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a javascript function that runs a PHP script to save data.

The problem I have is that after the $.ajax POST javascript runs, it refreshs my page and I need to avoid that.  I read that using "button" was the problem but couldn't get it to work with an input field.

Here's my form with one sample field from it:

```
<form id="SaveMarker" name="SaveMarker" method="POST" action="ajax-save.php">
    <label for="pName"><span>Location Name :</span>
    <input type="text" maxlength="75" placeholder="Enter Name" class="save-name" name="pName"></label>
</form>
```

And a "button" which is actually just a text link that the user clicks to save.

```
<button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Save Marker Details</button>
```

And this is the javascript that is called (via a Google Maps listener):

```
function save_marker(Marker, mName, mAddress, mType, replaceWin)
            {
                //Save new marker using jQuery Ajax
                var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
                var myData = {name : mName, address : mAddress, latlang : mLatLang, type : mType }; //post variables
                console.log(replaceWin);        
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "map_process.php",
                  data: myData,
                  success:function(data){
                        replaceWin.html(data); //replace info window with new html
                        Marker.setDraggable(false); //set marker to fixed
                        Marker.setIcon('http://www.sacgrid.com/img/pin_blue.png'); //replace icon
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }`
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with my form, my button element or javascript?  Thanks is advance, been working on this for 2 days.

Comment: This is minor, but the </label> should go right after the </span> - the <input> isn't part of the label.

Comment: Is the page it is on called ajax-save.php? Try removing the action='ajax-save.php' to action='' in your opening form element.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but didn't work, but apparently because I was not using type="button" on the button.

Comment: Good point on the </label>, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the type button to `button`, this way the `<form>` wont' be submited.

```
<button name="save-marker" type="button" class="save-marker">Save Marker Details</button>
```